# Fading Memory Model integration

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

Hey guys can someone please help me with this integral:
[FMM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8gcV.png)

I get that the dirac delta function is 1 when $$\tau=0$$ and it equals 0 otherwise, i just dont get how to change the integral limits when i plug in $$\tau=0$$
Thanks in advance

Comment: The integral there is just $e^{-\alpha_i(t-0)}=e^{-\alpha_i t}$ if $t>0$ and $0$ if $t<0$. It is not really well-defined at $t=0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, the delta function is not "1 when t= 0".  You are mistaken about that.

It would be better to remember that the defining property of the delta function is that $\int_a^b f(t)\delta(t) dt= f(0)$ if $a\le 0\le b$, 0 otherwise.

So $\int_0^\infty e^{-a_i(t-\tau)}\delta(t)dt$ is equal to $e^{a_i\tau}$ if $t\ge 0$, 0 otherwise.